# Query on OpenEvent's works perfectly, until including the property "SubscriberKey"

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, fuel-sdk

Using the Python library FuelSDK for Salesforce ExactTarget Marketing Cloud to query **OpenEvent**'s in a time period, I can successfully retrieve more than 20,000 opens for a specified time period. This is with specified properties
`et_event.props = ["SendID", "EventDate", "EventType"]`.

But when I simply change the properties to
`et_event.props = ["SubscriberKey", "SendID", "EventDate", "EventType"]`,
the call returns 0 users (and takes much longer).

According to documentation ([OpenEvent](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/openevent/)), `"SubscriberKey"` should be in there, so this seems to be a bug. Is this being fixed currently, and is there a way for me to be notified when it is?

Comment: Of the 20,000 OpenEvents you've retrieved without the SK, are they for the business unit (clientID) you're expecting?

Comment: Hmm, I added "Client" to the props and it returned 0 results. (I separately tried "ClientID" and "clientID" as well.) How can I find out the answer to your question?

Comment: Try Client.ID per this [Open Tracking](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/tracking/open-tracking.html) wiki page.  Subscriber and activity scope is dictated by SFMC account type.  Subscribers exist at the parent level, but their activity may not.

Comment: thanks for that link! separately, somebody just gave me new auth params (clientid and clientsecret) to an account with more permissions (the parent account, I believe) and now i CAN retrieve results with SubscriberKey.

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up simply being the auth parameters (clientid and clientsecret). I believe they were to a child account of the account whose parameters ended up allowing me to be successful in retrieving all fields, like `"SubscriberKey"`.